# change dropdown text colour from selected text

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a dropdown which contain list of text, then i want have different color of select text and color the text from the dropdown item.

```
    DropdownButton<String>(
                          hint: Text(
                            'Topic',
                            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Cairo', fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                          isExpanded: true,
                          value: dropdownValue,
                          dropdownColor: Colors.black,
                          elevation: 4,
//notices 1
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.deepPurple, fontFamily: 'Cairo'),
                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              dropdownValue = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: tpoicList
                              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Container(
                                // alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                child: Text(
                                  value,
                                  style: const 
//notices 2
TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        )
```

i notices that in the notice 1 style is also affect the notice 2 style. All i want to is to have different color in the text dropdown and selected text

what i am trying to archive
[image]

In the image you will notices the background color is different from the text color also if i select a item from the select item, the text should be in another colors

Comment: Can you share an example of what it is you exactly want? Visual example will be the most beneficial.

Comment: YES.. i will update the question now

Comment: [This](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/selectedItemBuilder.html) might help you out.

Comment: @tomerpacific the code is working fine but the issue text color and selected text color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DropdownButton` has a `selectedItemBuilder` parameter that should solve your problem. Add something like this to your code:

```dart
  selectedItemBuilder: (context) {
    final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> list = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < tpoicList.lenght; i++) {
      list.add(DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: tpoicList[i],
        child: Container(
          child: Text(
            value,
            style: i == dropdownValue? 
            [YourNewTextStyle],
            const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }
    return list;
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

[official] [change dropdown text colour from selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71055087/change-dropdown-text-colour-from-selected-text)

```
selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
    return tpoicList.map((String value) {
      return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(
          dropdownValue,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  },
```